# Javascript Form Using "$(this)"

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have an html form with a bunch of checkboxes. Each checkbox is described as this:

```
echo "<td>"
    echo "<input type = \"checkbox\" name=\"name\" value=\"$name\">";
    echo "<input type = \"hidden\" name=\"user\" value=\"$user\">"; 
echo "</td>"
```

Then I have a submit button that when clicked will run some javascript:

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" name =\"send\" value=\"Submit\" onclick=\"get_checked(form)\">";
```

Now my javascript:

```
function get_checked(form){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {         
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
            $(this).find("input[name]").each(function(index, node){
                formData[node.name] = node.value;
                alert (node.name + node.value);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I want to find every checked checkbox and then print out each of the name/value pairs for the checkbox. But it is not working as nothing gets alerted and I think I might be using $(this) improperly because this works when I use .each:

```
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
    testname_checked[i] = $(this).val();
    alert(testname_checked[i]);
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: $(this).find... will look for elements that are descendants of the checkbox (I doubt it has any).

Comment: When you submit the form you are attaching event handlers and you do not cancel the form submission. And what are you selecting that is a child of a checkbox?

Comment: So it looks like you are, in a click handler, attaching a change handler. That isn't right. You need to just attach a change handler.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a click handler to the checkboxes.

```
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    $(this).next("input[type=hidden]").val(this.checked ? this.value : '');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but i created this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thedole/88kapn0c/) with my interpretation of what your intent is.

This is the code

```
$('#btn').click(function (e){
        var formData = {};
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
                formData[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        }
    });
    console.log(formData);
});
```

I attached the click event in js, but that bit shouldn't be an issue. I removed the onChange event stuff as I didn't think this was your intent, and it didn't really make sense to mix it in the way you did. And used a console log instead of alert as I find it easier on the eyes, but otherwise changed as little as possible.